# SKScene's update method gets a "currentTime" that is different from CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

The problem can be reproduced in an freshly created SpriteKit project.

After creating a new project, I add two lines to the **update:** method of the **MyScene** class:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    NSLog(@"               currentTime = %f", currentTime);
    NSLog(@"CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() = %f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent());
}
```

Running this shows that **currentTime** is several orders of magnitude smaller than the time returned by **CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()**. I searched for possible reasons, but found none. The only possibility I could think of is that **currentTime** is the time frame since some other date than 00:00:00 01.01.2000, but I have no idea what other reference point it would be using, and found nothing when searching online either.

What can I do to get the current time, calculated by the same rules that are used to calculate **currentTime**?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, unless you're willing to disassemble and understand the Sprite Kit framework code.

Though the problem is most likely explained by Sprite Kit taking CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent at an earlier point in time, which is then passed into the update: method. Simply the overhead of sending that message to the scene means that the two times can't be the same. Or the currentTime may not be obtained by CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent but some other means.

What you can do is to get the currentTime of the very first time update: runs and store it in an ivar. You can then use this time as the reference time for the scene.

Comment: I doubt that it's just because Sprite Kit is taking the time a bit earlier. I just ran the code again, this is the output for one update:
CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() = 432056236.856374
               currentTime = 4973700.943797 ... The difference is roughly 430000000 seconds.

Comment: The CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent is exactly what I would expect (13.69 years from 2001). The currentTime is strange. That's about 57 days. Sorry, no idea.

Comment: "system time" as it says in the docs may relate to the time since the device (operating system) was last started. Try rebooting the device, see if the time difference is less than a day.

Comment: I am running this on the emulator. Neither the emulator nor the mac have been running for 57 days straight. Can I somehow simulate a restart on the emulator?

Comment: My currentTime is 13.8 days. I last rebooted 22 days ago, and I started my simulator yesterday. If you need absolute time, use CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent. It's clear that currentTime is something else.

Answer (score 1):

currentTime is a CFTimeInterval, so I expect it is the interval between some point in time and the current time - probably the interval since a scene was started. If you let your scene running for a minute, do the values get close to 60.0 (60 seconds)?

CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent is a CFAbsoluteTime, that is the number of seconds since Jan 1st 2001, so that should always be around 500 million or so.

Comment: This seems to be correct. The [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW7) says: "Here are the steps in the rendering loop:

The scene’s `update:` method is called with **the time elapsed so far in the simulation**." [emphasis mine]